# How do I count word occurrence in each line if the word is in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count the number of positive, negative, and neutral words in each line. I have a text file containing lines of reviews called reviews.txt.

My Code:

```
poswords = {} #contains positive words
negwords = {} #contains negative words
with open(path + "reviews.txt", 'r') as f:
    possum = 0
    negsum = 0
    neutsum = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        lower = line.lower()
        for word in lower.split():
            if word in poswords:
                possum += 1
            elif word in negwords:
                negsum += 1
            else:
                neutsum += 1
print(possum)
print(negsum)
print(neutsum)
```

Output:

```
1401
633
18351
```

Instead of counting positive, negative, and neutral words for the whole text file, how do I show the count for each line?

Comment: Initialize the variables as 0 inside the `for` loop for lines and print their corresponding values in the same loop as well.

Comment: Consider moving the `print` to a different indentation ;)

Comment: Thank you both of your suggestions helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put last 3 print statements inside for loop. Like

```
poswords = {} #contains positive words
negwords = {} #contains negative words
with open(path + "reviews.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        possum = 0
        negsum = 0
        neutsum = 0
        lower = line.lower()
        for word in lower.split():
            if word in poswords:
                possum += 1
            elif word in negwords:
                negsum += 1
            else:
                neutsum += 1
        print("Line: ", line)
        print(possum)
        print(negsum)
        print(neutsum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your count variables back to zero for each line and then print the variables after going through the line.

```
poswords = {} #contains positive words
negwords = {} #contains negative words
with open(path + "reviews.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        possum = 0
        negsum = 0
        neutsum = 0 
        lower = line.lower()    
        for word in lower.split():
            if word in poswords:
                possum += 1
            elif word in negwords:
                negsum += 1
            else:
                neutsum += 1
        print("\n", line)
        print(possum)
        print(negsum)
        print(neutsum)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `re` as well:

```
poswords = {...}
negwords = {...}
pos = '|'.join(poswords)
neg = '|'.join(negwords)

with open("reviews.txt", 'r') as f:
    matches = re.findall(f'({pos})|({neg})|(\w+)', f.read())
positive, negitive, neutral = (sum(map(bool, g)) for g in zip(*matches))
```